# Maven plugin Run after Selenium Test

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I am developing Selenium tests to test various web applications. Part of my requirements is the have the test Start the server, run the test, then stop the server.

I can have the test start the server, but it attempts to stop the server before the test is even started. Is there a phase condition for this?

My pom.xml `<plugins></plugins>` is as follows

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>cnphi.ft</groupId>
<artifactId>ping</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ping</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cnphi.ft</groupId>
        <artifactId>functional-test-base</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.45.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <id>startServer</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>start.bat</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Create directories to store screenshots -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Create Screenshot Directory</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo message="Creating test output directory" />
                            <mkdir dir="./target/Screenshots/Success" />
                            <mkdir dir="./target/Screenshots/ErrorsAndFailures" />
                            <mkdir dir="./target/Screenshots/Ignored" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- End create directories -->


        <!-- RUN TESTS AS INTEGRATION TESTS -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>

                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- END INTEGRATION TEST CONFIGURATION -->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <id>stopServer</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>stop.bat</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-antrun-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.8,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>run</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>


<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <reports>
                        <report>failsafe-report-only</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: Are you trying to start your web application server (tomcat) with the exec-maven-plugin ?

Comment: no I am starting a websphere, I can make the server start, then the test runs. My only issue is making the server stop after the test has run

Comment: As far as i know for websphere exist a maven plugin liberty-maven-plugin (just ask google). to do such things...